# Gets wrong output with nested XML Tags

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

This piece of code takes an XDocument I generate and save it as an XML file:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        dic.Add("title", "Ny Aftale");
        dic.Add("paragraph0", "Some text here");
        dic.Add("paragraph1", "Some more text on a new line here");
        dic.Add("paragraph2", "<list>\t\n<li>A point</li>\n<li>another point</li></list>");
        dic.Add("header", "<author>Mads</author>\n<date>" + new DateTime().ToShortDateString() + "</date>\n<subject>Ny HIF Aftale</subject>");
        XDocument xd = WordFileGenerator.Parse(dic);
        string path = "C:\\Users\\Vipar\\Desktop";
        using (var writer = new XmlTextWriter(path + "\\test.xml", new UTF8Encoding(false)))
        {
            xd.Save(writer);
        };
    }
```

The problem is, that the nested tags in this dictionary (since I make the dictionary into an XML document, don't ask) are made into another representation of them, than what they are supposed to be. Given the above dictionary here is what I get as output:

```
<document>
<title>Ny Aftale</title>
<paragraph>Some text here</paragraph>
<paragraph>Some more text on a new line here</paragraph>
<paragraph>
  &lt;list&gt;  
  &lt;li&gt;A point&lt;/li&gt;
  &lt;li&gt;another point&lt;/li&gt;&lt;/list&gt;
</paragraph>
  <header>
  &lt;author&gt;Mads&lt;/author&gt;
  &lt;date&gt;01-01-0001&lt;/date&gt;
  &lt;subject&gt;Ny HIF Aftale&lt;/subject&gt;
  </header>
</document>
```

The code I use to generate this looks like this:

```
    public static XDocument Parse(Dictionary<String, String> dic)
    {
        XDocument newXDoc = new XDocument();
        newXDoc.Add(new XElement("document",
            new XElement("title", dic["title"]),
            dic.Where((kvp) => kvp.Key.ToLower().StartsWith("paragraph"))
                .Select(kvp => new XElement(kvp.Key.Substring(0,9), kvp.Value)),
            new XElement("header", dic["header"])
        )
    );

        return newXDoc;
    }
```

The weird conversion happens when I place the information on the XDocument.

How do I fix this nested tags problem..?

Comment: `<list>` is just a string not a nested tag that linq2xml will escape to &lt;list&gt;

Comment: I would think the same @xeondev . But it still does it.

Comment: I can't see any weird here, string works this way, if you wan't nested tag i would go for `Dictionary<string, XElement>` and add an XElement for the header.

Comment: I agree with xeondev, you will either need to put `XElement` values into your dictionary or you will need to parse the values using `XElement.Parse(kvp.Value)`. But that will only work if the contents is well-formed XML element markup, for your `paragraph0` and `paragraph1` value you can't use that approach, you would need to wrap all contents into tags.